How to authenticate users by Keycloak integrated in Spring Boot?
In my web application, the login function is implemented using Keycloak. In one of the web pages, there is an input box for password and a cancel button. The function of this web page is when a user wants to cancel his booking, he needs to enter his password again and then clicks the cancel button.
How can I authenticate the user after he enters his password?
My thought is if I can get the password the user registered with Keycloak, I can compare the registered password with the password the user re-enters. If both passwords are the same, the REST API corresponding to cancellation of booking can be accessed. Is my thought correct?

A system that would let you query for someone's password would be very insecure.
If you want the user to be reauthenticated with Keycloak you can use the prompt=login in your authorization request and then check that the id_token's auth_time claim is recent.
http(s)://{host}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth?prompt=login...

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/

I did some research on the documentation of Keycloak and in section 2.3.12 Parameters forwarding, it says "login - SSO will be ignored and the Keycloak login page will always be shown, even if the user is already authenticated". If the user clicks the cancel button and Keycloak login page will be shown in order to re-authenticate the user, this implementation is not what I want. I've watched lots of videos on YouTube but none of them provides me with the information I need.  https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/
